# Azure Storage Account geo-replication to China Azure DataCenter China Azure region

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-china

I tried to geo-replicate my storage account which is in East Asia region (Hong Kong location) to China Azure DataCenter (China North, China East) but I couldn't find the China DataCenter while creating stroage account geo-replication.

Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please tell me how can I do this.

Simple answer is that you can't. There are 2 reasons for that:

1. You can't select a region for geo-replication. It is automatically selected by Azure for you.
2. Even if you were able to do so, your particular scenario for geo-replicating between Azure General and Azure China will not work as Azure China is a special region and you can't create an Azure Subscription there just like that (same goes for Azure Germany and Azure Government).

Answer (score 2):

As Gaurav Mantri mentioned that we can't select a region for geo-replication. We could get the detail info about [Azure Storage replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#geo-redundant-storage) from Azure official document.

> When you create a storage account, you select the primary region for the account. **The secondary region is determined based on the primary region, and cannot be changed**. The following table shows the primary and secondary region pairings.

[image]

We also could get more info from the [Azure region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/) document.

> [Azure in China](https://www.azure.cn/) is available through a unique partnership between Microsoft and 21Vianet, one of the country’s largest Internet providers.
>
> [Azure Germany](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/clouds/germany/) provides services under a data trustee model. Customer data remains in Germany under the control of T-Systems International GmbH, a subsidiary of Deutsche Telekom, acting as the German data trustee.

Answer (score 0):

East Asia is a region in Azure public cloud where as China North/East are regions in Azure China which is a separate sovereign cloud. For more details, please refer to following :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/china/